# How to read the values in the String

Tags: javascript

If the user enters the text in the text box I want to display a number of occurences of each 26 letters. Why does this code not work?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <form id="firstForm">
         <br>
         <textarea rows="5" cols="50" id="usertext">The Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over the Lazy Dogs
         </textarea>
         <br>
         <br>
         <input type="button" value ="Image Chart" onclick="Alphabets()"
      </form>
      <br>
      <br>

      <div id="test1"> </div>
      <script> 
         function Alphabets(){

            var userinput = document.getElementById("usertext").value; 
            var A = 'A'| 'a';
            var B = 'B'|'b';
            var C = 'C'|'c';

            A = userinput / A;
            B = userinput / B;
            C = userinput / C ;

            document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML = A;  
         }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is `A = userinput / A;`?

Comment: You know what `var A = 'A'| 'a';` does?

Comment: I just build up a logic i know it is a bad one thats why i posted the question here

Comment: that doesn't asnwer the question. What do you think `A = 'A'|'a';` and `A = userinput / A` do?

Comment: A hold the value A or a then userinput/ A gives me the count of how many A or a are there in the string, this is what i thought it would do but it returs a NAN which means not a number

Comment: I just want to show a count of alphabets are there in the text area

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This counts the number of alphabet a

```
var temp = "The Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over the Lazy Dogs";

console.log((temp.match(/a|A/g) || []).length);
```

Comment: Thankyou can you explain the part " g) || []).length " and when i store this value to A and try to show it it says Undefined. why?

Comment: The ``g`` is an optional search flag that refers to global, it makes the call to grab all the matches, if you remove it then it will only grab the first one.  The ``|| []`` part is for empty searches, if nothing found then just return an empty array.

Comment: im using this to store this to and variable but when i display the variable it says undefined.  var temp = "The Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over the Lazy Dogs";

    var A =   console.log((temp.match(/a|A/g) || []).length);

document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML = A;

Comment: remove console.log, it writes to console which you can view using Firebug or whichever debugging tool your browser has